# Handsontable and cells colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have a handsontable which contains 2 rows of 3 dates, and I would like to change the color in green when a new date is inserted in a non-empty cell.

my function for the handsontable is

```
function startperspective() {

    $.getJSON("/Reporting/getperspective", function(data) {
        var reg = new RegExp('^((0[1-9]{1}|[12]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[01]{1})\/(0[1-9]{1}|1[012]{1})\/[0-9]{4}$)');
        if (data !== null) {
            $("#old_tab_handsontable").handsontable({
                data: data,
                colHeaders: ['Date Perspective', 'Date Archive', 'Date des valeurs finales'],
                columns: [
                    {data: 'datePers', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'},
                    {data: 'dateArchive', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'},
                    {data: 'dateDef', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}
                ],
                colWidths: [200, 200, 200],
                fillHandle: false,
                onBeforeChange: function(data) {
                    for (var ind = data.length - 1; ind >= 0; ind--) {
                        if ((!reg.test(data[ind][3]))) {
                            data[ind][3] = data[ind][2];
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (data[ind][3] !== data[ind][2]) {
                                TabChange = true;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

TabChange is a boolean to check if I have a new cell for the save or not. I think I need something in 'onBeforeChange' off my handsontable, but I don't know what.

And I would like to avoid to change the cellProperties, because it will remove the datepicker for my handsontable.

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, after there is a change, you want to compare the before and after values, and if it changed from one date to another date then you want to color that cell green.

If this is the case, then I would use afterChange

```
afterChange: function(changes, source){

    if (source=== 'loadData') {
        return; //don't do anything as this is called when table is loaded
    }
    var rowIndex = changes[0];
    var col = changes[1];
    var oldCellValue = changes[2];
    var newCellValue = changes[3];

    //compare oldCellValue with newCellValue to ensure it is the change you are after
    //you need to apply the logic you need but for example:
    if(oldCellValue !== newCellValue){
        //Here you set the background color to green
    }
}
```

You might also like to check out [conditional formatting](http://handsontable.com/demo/conditional.html)